# Java create key value pair for table with multiple column

Tags: java, key-value, keyvaluepair

I have to create table like below using key value pair

```
Column1     Column2     Column3                     Column4     Column5     Column6
23          ASD         10 Oct 2016(Current Date)   value11     value11     value11
78          XYZ         10 Oct 2016(Current Date)   value12     value14     value15
80          XYA         10 Oct 2016(Current Date)   value9      value8      value5
```

Is that possible?

And after that i have to fetch row with using Column1 value.

if yes so please guide me for this.

I am using JAVA with Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Hm, you could use either Map<String, List<String>> (or List<Object>, if the date shall be a Date), or Map<String, Map<String, Object>> if you want each row being a Map (ColumnName -> Value). Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Or Map<Integer, ...> if your Column1 is an integer value...

Answer (score 0):

Create a table bean which contains getters & setters of all the columns,Then create a MAP with key as column one and value as table bean,

**TableBean.java**

```
public class TableBean{
    private String column1;
    private String column2;
    //define all the fields along with setters & getters
}
```

Then create a **List< TableBean>** now you are in a good shape to get the column1 and printing the table bean.Let me know for any more queries.

The following [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456192/get-specific-objects-from-arraylist-when-objects-were-added-anonymously) question will help you to get the object from TableBean.